# How to set a compiler in Qt?

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, qt-creator

I'm totally new with Qt and I downloaded the offline version " Qt 5.3.2 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013, OpenGL, 573 MB)"

I'm unable to compile my project.

I have:

Qt Creator 3.2.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.3.2 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

In my Build & Run, I have,
For the kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit
For Qt version: Qt 5.3 MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit

and there is nothing for the compilers tab. I don't know what I should put in that section. What did I miss?

I got the following error message while trying to compile my project:

> 14:44:12: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
>
> Error while building/deploying project TextFinder (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3
>
> MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit) When executing step "Make"

and

> Qt creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in
> the kit options.

Comment: qt is a library. do you have a c/c++ compiler and tool chain (e.g. make + linker) installed?

Comment: Get the online installer. Install MinGW Qt and MinGW toolchain with it. Or install Visual C++ from MS if you want to use that.

Comment: to MarcB I've a c/c++ compiler downloaded from cygwin. I tried but it didn't work.
to hyde Are there difference between MinGW Qt/toolchain and the one of Visual C++"?

I guess I will try download MinGW Qt and MinGW toolchain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Tools->Options->Build & Run` and on the `Compilers` tab click `Add` to add a new compiler. You can also manage kits on the `Kits` tab. Don't forget to setup `qmake` on the `Qt Versions` tab.

Also if you want the `MSVC` version of `Qt` you need to install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010` or `2013` depending on the version of `Qt` you use.

If you are a beginner I recommend you download the `MinGW` version from [qt-project.org](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482_opengl-5.3.2.exe) and everything should work just fine.

`MinGW` versions use the windows versions of `GCC` while `VS` uses Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: The qmake is already set on Qt versions.
I put the gcc.exe downloaded from cygwin in compiler, I got another different error messsage "Multiple target patterns. stop." What should I do next?

Comment: Have you tried using the link for the offline installer or you need Qt Creator with a different/more than one version of Qt?

Comment: @luliu not yet because I have "Qt 5.3.2 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013, OpenGL, 573 MB)" installed. If I download from the link you provided, do I have to uninstall the current version I have?

Comment: AFAIK you don't have to uninstall anything, nor conflicts should occur. The version i linked up should work fine.

Comment: Tyvm for the link with mingw. It works. I can compile :)