# I can't compile my project in QT

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I've installed QT on my virtual machine running Ubuntu and started a new project but when I try to compile and run it I get this error:

"Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project PoshetPOP3 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make" "

Issues view says :"QT Creator needs a compiler set up to build.Configure a compiler in the kit options"

*"PoshetPOP3" my project name.
I also have QT installed on my host machine(windows 10) and it works perfectly.

Why do I get it and how can I fix this error?

An answer would be much apreciated,thank you!

Comment: Neither can I... (answering to the subject line)

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306733/how-to-set-a-compiler-in-qt)

Comment: What the "issues view" says?

Comment: So the error message tells you that "the Issues view" contains vital information, but you don't tell us what it says?  How are we supposed to help.  Have a downvote.

Comment: This is what "the issues view" says :"QT Creator needs a compiler set up to build.Configure a compiler in the kit options".I go to kit options and the auto-detected compiler I found this: "Desktop Qt 5.5.1 GCC 64bit(default)" but it seems that it is not set.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I managed to work it out by doing this:

sudo apt-get install g++

sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools

And then restart the QT.Sorry for the poor research.